# Android Imageview on touch event

Tags: android

I am creating a android application.
Here  I have a imageview .
my goal is to get next picture from database when move the finger on image

```
float nPicturePositionM = 0;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    boolean aHandledL = false;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        float nNewPicturePosL = event.getX();
        if (nPicturePositionM < nNewPicturePosL) {
            nPicturePositionM = nNewPicturePosL;
            GetPictures(true);
        } else {
            nPicturePositionM = nNewPicturePosL;
            GetPictures(false);
        }
        aHandledL = true;
    }

    return aHandledL;

    //return false;
}
```

How can i handle it using touch event? Image should slide as in we do it in gallery

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly you declare an imageview in your xml :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Then in your activity you initialize the component :

private ImageView image1;

In onCreate :

```
this.image1= (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
this.image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.NAMEOFIMAGE);
```

The next step is detecting if the image is "clicked". You can then use an online database or an SQLite database to save the images or the path to the images, the database part of it is a large part to teach from scratch depending which route you want to go with:

```
       this.image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view == findViewById(R.id.imageview1)) {     
                         //PUT IN CODE HERE TO GET NEXT IMAGE
            }
            }
        });
```

I hope this helps. Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: How can i handle it using touch event? Image should slide as in we do it in gallery

Comment: sure, use setOnTouchListener instead of setOnClickListener

Comment: I used setOnTouchListener and image moved but its too slow and it skips the image in between. i have provided my code above . Can u please have a look whats wrong in that and how can i solve it?

Comment: I'm not too sure, could have something to do with the refresh rate. I will have a look into it and get back to you

Comment: I want to get next and preview pictures based on left and right sliding . can u help me out how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by preview? Do you want to show the main image and also show a mini thumbnail of the next image depending on which direction they slide?

If that's the case then add an Imageview to your XML in the same way as you did for the main image and load the image into that imageview depending on what the next image is in the database

Comment: It was a spelling mistake . On create event i m showing one image , when i slide right i want to see next image from database and then when i slide left i want to see the previous image from database.

Comment: Ok cool, is it working correctly now? If it is, good work! this technique can be used in all aspects of Android development.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the array of image from your database and set that on the basis of Touch...like..

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {
                    img.setImageURI(uri[pos]);
                    pos++;
                    return false;
            }
        });
```